# Use Graph inside a multitenant azure function (App credentials)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

i 'm working on an azure functions that make some graph call to different tenant (multitenant)
I want to reuse a GraphServiceClient and leveraging token cache
I generate the GraphServiceClient in this way:

```
List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var authProvider = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("e9b93362-a788-4644-8623-da9f4d4776a7")
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
            .WithClientSecret("fkpx53225awyQJDHV35:^][")
            .Build();

        var dd = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(authProvider, scopes.ToArray(),"ugochotmail.onmicrosoft.com");
        var appGraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(dd);
```

Than i should call

```
authResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                .ExecuteAsync();
```

To obtain a token for the app to access the specific tenant.
The problem is in the authentication provider that is call on every send request but doen't offer a parameter with the tenant name

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var token = await GetTokenAsync();
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
    }
```

At the moment i just add a property to the Authentication provider to set the tenant. It works but i would like to know if there is a better solution

Comment: Hi, may I know if the first block and second block of code are in the method `GetTokenAsync()` in third block code ? And I'm not clear about your requirement, do you mean you want to add a parameter in the method `GetTokenAsync()` to specify the tenant ?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below works ? If I misunderstood your requirement, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, it seems your function doesn't allow a parameter which specify the tenant name and then use the tenant name when do `GetTokenAsync()` method. And now you can just hardcode the tenant name in the line `new MsalAuthenticationProvider(...` to specify the tenant.

For this problem, I think you can add a variable named `tenant` in the "**Application settings**" of your function app (as below screenshot show).

[image]

Then add a line of code `string tenant = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tenant");` above `var token = await GetTokenAsync();`

After that, you can add parameter in method `GetTokenAsync()` like `GetTokenAsync(tenant)`. Then you do not need to hardcode tenant name in code, you just need to change the tenant name in "**Application settings**" of your function.

If I misunderstand your requirement, please provide more details.

=============================**Update**===============================

It seems you just want to specify the tenant in your code by a parameter, but not add the tenant name as a property in `var dd = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(authProvider, scopes.ToArray(),"tenant name");`. If so, you can refer to the code below (just add a line `.WithTenantId("xxx.onmicrosoft.com")` when do `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`)
[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your support. No this is not the case: i want to build a confidential client application without specify the tenant. Then I generate the authprovider and than i pass it to the GraphServiceClient. Then i want to pass the tenant when i make a specific request. Again i'm in a multitenant azure function. In this way i can reuse all the stuff and have token cache, The problem is how to pass the tenant to the authprovider

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't fix the problem as, in a multitenant, the target tenant is send as a parameter to the function. I'm working on an other approach i will come back when i will finish tests.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I review your description and your new comments. It seems you just want to specify the tenant in your code by a parameter, but not add the tenant name as a property in `var dd = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(authProvider, scopes.ToArray(),"tenant name");`. If so, please refer to the "Update" of my answer.